# Definir nome de remetente por meio da ResetPasswordNotification

Tags: laravel

Estou utilizando Notification no Laravel para enviar emails de redefinição de senha. Meu método toMail está assim:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Link para redefinição de senha')
                ->greeting('Redefinir senha!')
                ->line('Clique no botão abaixo para redefinir sua senha.')
                ->action('Trocar senha', url('password/reset', $this->token))
                ->line('Qualquer dúvida estamos a disposição!');
}
```

Quando o email chega na caixa do usuário, aparece como remetente o nome: Example. Como posso definir o nome da minha aplicação como remetente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A configuração do e-mail que é responsável em enviar ao usuário a redefinição de senha, está em: `app/config/mail.php`, abre o arquivo e na chave de configuração `from`, altere conforme suas configurações:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

mas, observe que se suas configurações estiverem no arquivo `.env`, então, a alteração tem que ser feita nessa parte:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
```

ou seja, depende como sua aplicação está configurada, se utilizar tudo no arquivo `.env` altere nele se for no arquivo de configuração somente altere no `mail.php`. Geralmente a alteração é feita no `mail.php` nessa determinada configuração de remetente (*tanto e-mail, quanto ao nome do mesmo*).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Laravel - API new Message](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage.html)
- [Laravel - Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration)
- [Laravel - Resetting Passwords](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords)